# Position of clicked element (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my example fiddle I get the `.innerText` of my clicked Element. How can I get on this way (or a better?) the index of my clicked item?

Without jQuery would be awesome because I want to learn living without jQuery :D

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("lol");

for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
el[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     console.log(e.target.innerText)
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6s8c1y8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **`getElementsByClassName`** Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. As we are suppose to use `Array#indexOf` method, input has to be `array`
- Use [**`Array#from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), it creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.
- Use [**`Array#indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the index of `element`

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("lol");
var arrElems = Array.from(el);
//Or var arrElems = [].slice.call(el);
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("text is:   " + e.target.innerText);
    console.log("Index is:   " + arrElems.indexOf(e.target));
  });
}
```

```css
.lol {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol">
  1
</div>
<div class="lol">
  2
</div>
<div class="lol">
  3
</div>
<div class="lol">
  4
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/y6s8c1y8/3/)

Comment: I like your second way, it's compatible with IE :)
Thanks!

Comment: As you're using `Array.from` you could even use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `var arrElems = [...el]`.

Comment: Do you have an example evolutionxbox? :)